# how to save the result of a partition into an existing column instead of an additional column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition

I have a table as follows:

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | TRUE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | TRUE |

I have a query such as

```
SELECT *, ORDER = MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS RECENT
FROM MY_TABLE
```

My table already has a column called RECENT that has default TRUE values. How can I write the partition so that it replaces the current values within that column with the new values, instead of adding a second column to the table called RECENT also. (Basically what can I use instead of having "AS RECENT" after my partition statement). I would like the table to end up looking like:

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | FALSE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | FALSE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | FALSE |

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide some example data from your table

Comment: Just added a table of example data

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the view you want:

```sql
SELECT
    * EXCLUDE RECENT,
    "ORDER" = MAX("ORDER") OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS RECENT
FROM
    MY_TABLE
;
```

You need to surround "ORDER" in quotations to stop it being treated as a keyword.

Comment: Just added a table to show some example data

Comment: @Angie thanks. The SQL I provided seems to provide the answer you are looking for in my test environment. Although I notice you have created another question where you want to update the values in the table, rather than just have a SELECT view of the table.